# Magento2 : Vat Field Validation on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

Condition is this.

VAT textfield  -  require field validation off  when country selected is USA

VAT textfield  -  require field validation on  when country selected is other than USA

Comment: This field is your custom field?

Comment: no not a custom field. it is a system field  of  VAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's done Using override

```
Magento_Checkout/web/js/shipping.js
```

validation working.

In this file there are different types of method related to method add jquery validation.
Like method i have used : saveNewAddress and setShippingInformation.